# Cobertura 2.0.3 with JDK 1.6.0_35 failed to instrument classes

Tags: ant, cobertura

I am trying to run cobertura through ant, using jdk1.6.0.35, but getting exception while instrumentation. How to solve it?
The exception message as following:

```
[cobertura-instrument] [12/06 13:19:26] [WARN] CoberturaInstrumenter: Unable to instrument file D:\workcontext\niyong_crm_v1_0\crm\code\ulcif\web\WEB-INF\classes\com\ulic\ulcif\ws\service\impl\CustomerCIImpl.class
[cobertura-instrument] java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: net/sourceforge/cobertura/instrument/pass1/DetectIgnoredCodeClassVisitor
[cobertura-instrument]  at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:149)
[cobertura-instrument]  at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:121)
[cobertura-instrument]  at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:234)
[cobertura-instrument]  at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(Main.java:298)
[cobertura-instrument]  at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentation(Main.java:307)
[cobertura-instrument]  at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.parseArguments(Main.java:399)
[cobertura-instrument]  at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.main(Main.java:421)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added Cobertura to your ant task?

see:
https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/Ant-Task-Reference

Mine looks like this:

```
    <target name="process-classes" depends="compile" description="post-process the generated files from compilation, for example to do bytecode enhancement on Java classes.">
        <path id="cobertura.auxpath">
              <pathelement path="${target.dir}/classes"/>
              <pathelement location="classes"/>
        </path>

        <mkdir dir="${target.dir}/cobertura-ser" />
        <mkdir dir="${target.dir}/cobertura-classes" />

        <!-- Copy all the files into the file that eventually get's built into the instrumented JAR -->
        <copy todir="${target.dir}/cobertura-classes">
            <fileset dir="${target.dir}/classes" /> 
        </copy>

        <!-- Instrument all the classes in place -->
        <cobertura-instrument todir="${target.dir}/cobertura-classes" 
            datafile="${target.dir}/cobertura-ser/cobertura.ser" 
            classpathref="cobertura.path">
            <fileset dir="${target.dir}/classes" >
                 <include name="**/*.class" />
                 <exclude name="**/*Test.class" />
            </fileset>
            <auxClasspath>
              <path refid="cobertura.auxpath" />
            </auxClasspath>
        </cobertura-instrument> 
    </target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved it by changing the asm-3.3.1 to asm-all-5.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/FAQ#classnotfoundexception-during-instrumentation:

"This is because during instrumentation in cobertura 2.0, we use ASM to rebuild the .class files. We rebuild the stackmap which is a requirement to be compatible with java 7 and anything after. This does not mean that we recompile the code, however ASM requires that we provide the binaries of the other classes just in case it needs to look up any super methods. To fix this we use an argument called auxClasspath."

You need to have asm , asm-analysis, asm-commons, asm-tree and asm-util jars.

Also, adding the auxpath your ant file (build.xml) should resolve the issue.
Try adding the following code:

```
<path id="cobertura.auxpath">
<pathelement location="${bin}"/>
    </path>

    <target name="instrument_coverage" depends="init_coverage"
        description="Instruments source code for coverage measurement">
        <cobertura-instrument datafile="${coverage.datafile}">
            <fileset refid="coverage-files"/>
        <auxClasspath>
              <path refid="cobertura.auxpath" />
            </auxClasspath>
        </cobertura-instrument>
    </target>
```

This worked for me.